# Display charger input current in App

Tags: android

I want to make an app that finds the amount of power the charger is supplying. There are apps like ampere that do it without root by somehow accessing this file **says so in settings**

> Sys/device/platform/mt6320-battery/power_supply/battery/BatteryAverageCurrent

How do I make my app access this file?
I tried getting there using explorer and this file contains an integer value of current in MA.

How do I display this on screen?

Comment: Please read this before asking your first question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _"How do I display this on screen?"_ Displaying a value in your Activity/Fragment is a really basic operation. If that's where you're stuck you should search for a good introductory book or tutorial on Android development.

Comment: I know how to display data. Question is, how do I access that system file from my app?